# How can I get TextMate to recognize intellisense for ASP.NET MVC Razor views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, intellisense, textmate, textmatebundles

I'm using TextMate on a Mac as a front end designer and trying to open cshtml (razor) views to just tweak html, but the html intellisense does not trigger.  How do i get html intellisense on the cshtml files?

Comment: I'm pretty sure TextMate doesn't have razor support.

Comment: I don't care so much about the razor support as the html intellisense.  It could be any other custom code in there and any custom file extension, but how do i get intellisense for html.

Comment: my only thought would be to figure out how to associate the `cshtml` file extension with the `html` markup engine.

Answer (score 1):

TextMate doesn't have HTML intellisense. It has language-specific tab completion and dumb attribute completion on some languages but nothing that comes close to Visual Studio's "intellisense" or Eclipse's "content assist".

If you want to use its HTML-related features you only have to select **HTML** in the "Language" menu at the bottom of the window.

That said, I just saved a sample of .cshtml from a [random tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/asp.net/gg241199) and TextMate recognizes it as HTML automatically so I'm not sure what's going on.

There are a couple of ASP.NET oriented HTML bundles available, did you try them ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some information I found on associating file types in textmate. Hopefully it will be of assistance.

https://superuser.com/questions/40506/textmate-file-type-association
http://blog.macromates.com/2007/file-type-detection-rspec-rails

Ultimately, you need to tell TextMate to use the `html` engine with any file that has a `cshtml` or `vbhtml` extension.